# HTTPS - How to actually decrypt client request

Tags: python, sockets, encryption, https

I am using the **socket** library for handling **http** requests waiting on port **80** for connections (does not really matter right now), which works fine as all responses follow the following format

```
b"""GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36 OPR/70.0.3728.189
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: el-GR,el;q=0.9"""
```

if you open port **443** or just use **https** in any browser, when a request is made the data is encrypted. But how can you actually decrypt the data and interact with the client? I've seen many posts about this but no one explains how the data can actually be decrypted. The data that is received always  looks something like this and starts the same way with 0x16 and 0x03 bytes

```
b'\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xfc\x03\x03\xfb\'\xa3\xa5\xa4\x1cf\xd1w~(L\xb5%0,\xfb\xa57\xf4\x92\x03}\x84xCIA\xd9}]2 \x15ID\xafU\xb6\xe3\x9d\xbdr\x93 L\x98\rD\xca\xa7\x11\x89\x00`Q\xf5\th\xde\x85S\xf8Q\x98\x00"jj\x13\x03\x13\x01\x13\x02\xcc\xa9\xcc\xa8\xc0+\xc0/\xc0,\xc00\xc0\x13\xc0\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x00\n\x01\x00\x01\x91ZZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x0c\x00\x00\tlocalhost\x00\x17\x00\x00\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\n\x00\n\x00\x08\x9a\x9a\x00\x1d\x00\x17\x00\x18\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x0e\x00\x0c\x02h2\x08http/1.1\x00\x05\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x14\x00\x12\x04\x03\x08\x04\x04\x01\x05\x03\x08\x05\x05\x01\x08\x06\x06\x01\x02\x01\x00\x12\x00\x00\x003\x00+\x00)\x9a\x9a\x00\x01\x00\x00\x1d\x00 \xa5\x81S\xec\xf4I_\x08\xd2\n\xa6\xb5\xf6E\x9dE\xe6ha\xe7\xfdy\xdab=\xf4\xd3\x1b`V\x94F\x00-\x00\x02\x01\x01\x00+\x00\x0b\nZZ\x03\x04\x03\x03\x03\x02\x03\x01\x00\x1b\x00\x03\x02\x00\x02\xea\xea\x00\x01\x00\x00\x15\x00\xcf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

My question is how can I bring the **HTTPS** data into a form like the above. I've read about some specific handshake procedures but I could not find something that just answsers telling exactly what to do. Of course I am only asking for development purposes.

Comment: HTTPS is HTTP over SSL/TLS. This means your HTTP server needs to have an additional SSL/TLS layer on top of TCP and below HTTP. The [SSL module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) is used for this.

Comment: And your HTTP library should do the decryption for you. How did you get this data?